# Conditionally set value of other observations based on value in first observation

Tags: sas

If the value in my first observation is 0 I would like to set the value of all other observations to 1.  Otherwise do nothing. This needs to happen for each variable starting with the string "Rule" - How can I do this.

HAVE

| Acct | Rule1 | Rule2 | Rule3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

WANT

| Acct | Rule1 | Rule2 | Rule3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary array to hold the value of each rule for observation 1 (`_N_ = 1`). We'll compare this to every other observation.

```
data want;
    set have;

    array r[3] _TEMPORARY_;
    array rule[*] rule:;

    retain r;

    do i = 1 to dim(rule);
        if(_N_ = 1) then r[i] = rule[i];
            else if(r[i] = 0) then rule[i] = 1;
    end;

    drop i;
run;
```

Output:

```
acct    Rule1   Rule2   Rule3
1       1       0       0
2       0       1       1
3       1       1       1
```